# How to switch a text to lowercase within Pages

Tags: pages, formatting

Within `Pages`, how to switch a text selection to lowercase ( or to uppercase )?

My actual workaround is:

1. copy the text within `Pages`,
2. open `vi` without any file name,
3. paste the selected text,
4. keep the `~` pressed along the whole text,
5. select and copy the modified text within `vi`,
6. paste it back in `Pages`.

And to be honest, I don't find it either efficient or nice.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the text,
2. Edit (in Pages Menus),
3. Transformations,
4. Make Lower Case.

[Here](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/03/19/switch-uppercase-lowercase-mac/) is an article about this (with screenshots). The "transformations" are common to Apple apps, e.g. Notes and Text Edit.

For Text Edit, but not Pages, the transformations are in the Control-click menu. Also when editing with Safari in a StackExchange reply.

Comment: About the last §, I didn't find this function in FIrefox. Is it a function of Safari?

Comment: @dan. Yes, I am sure it is a function of Safari - not of the web site. I was, perhaps, too eager to include that without checking in other browsers.  Brave has transformations in its Edit menu, but not Control-click.  I guess it all depends how well the browser (or other app) is integrated with the features of macOS.

Comment: To add, as these are menu items, one can make custom keyboard shortcuts for them.